# Написать функцию которая принимает массив товаров и магазинов и возвращает лучшую цену товара

Tags: java, java-8

Написать функцию, которая принимает массив товаров и массив магазинов. Функция должна возвращать для каждого товара, лучшую цену и соответствующий магазин. Товары должны идти в том же порядке, что и в исходном массиве товаров.
Гарантируется, что:
каждый товар будет присутствовать хотя бы в одном магазине будет.
в магазине присутствуют только повторяющиеся товары

Решаю эту задачу, но не уверена в правильности алгоритма.
Обращаюсь с просьбой к профессионалам посмотреть, что я написала. и сказать что делаю верно. а что нет.
Вот мой код:

```
public static class Item{           // товары
        public int id;                  // id товара
        public  String name;            // наименование товара
    }
    public static class Shop{           //магазин
        public String name;             //название магазина
        public Price [] prices;         // массив цен товаров
    }
    public static class Price{          // Цены
        public int itemId;              // id  товара
        public int price;               // цена
    }
    public static class ItemWithBestPrice{  // лучший прайс
        public Item item;                   // товар
        public String shopName;             // наименование лучшего товара
        public int bestPrice;               // лучшая цена

        public ItemWithBestPrice(Item item, String shopName, int bestPrice){
            this.item = item;
            this.shopName = shopName;
            this.bestPrice = bestPrice;
        }
        public ItemWithBestPrice(){

        }
    }
public static ItemWithBestPrice[] findBestPrices(Item[] items, Shop[] shops){
        Price [] price = new Price[]{};
      //  ItemWithBestPrice newPrice = new ItemWithBestPrice();
        Shop shopsNew = new Shop();
        Item itemsNew = new Item();
        Price priceNew = new Price();
        int minPrice = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < shops.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j ++){
                for (int p = 0; p < price.length; p++){
                    if (price[p].price < minPrice){
                        itemsNew = items[j];
                        shopsNew = shops[i];
                        priceNew = price[p];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ItemWithBestPrice newPrice = new ItemWithBestPrice();
        newPrice.item = itemsNew;
        newPrice.shopName.equals(shopsNew);
        newPrice.bestPrice = priceNew[];

        return newPrice;
    }
```

У меня вопрос по return Получается после того как я создала объект ItemWithBestPrice newPrice = new ItemWithBestPrice(); Как мне правильно присвоить получившиеся параметры вот здесь: newPrice.bestPrice = priceNew; учитывая, что bestPrice - это int а priceNew это объект класса priceNew?

Помогите пожалуйста ))

Answer (score 1):

т.к. Вы "обратились с просьбой к профессионалам посмотреть", приведу пример "профессионального" ревью :)

```
public static class Item{           // товары
    public int id;                  // id товара
    public  String name;            // наименование товара
}
public static class Shop{           //магазин
    public String name;             //название магазина
    public Price [] prices;         // массив цен товаров
}
public static class Price{          // Цены
    public int itemId;              // id  товара
    public int price;               // цена
}
public static class ItemWithBestPrice{  // лучший прайс
    public Item item;                   // товар
    // TODO review: misleading comment "наименование лучшего товара"
    public String shopName;             // наименование лучшего товара
    public int bestPrice;               // лучшая цена

    public ItemWithBestPrice(Item item, String shopName, int bestPrice){
        this.item = item;
        this.shopName = shopName;
        this.bestPrice = bestPrice;
    }
    public ItemWithBestPrice(){

    }
}

public static ItemWithBestPrice[] findBestPrices(Item[] items, Shop[] shops){
    Price [] price = new Price[]{};
  //  ItemWithBestPrice newPrice = new ItemWithBestPrice();
    // TODO review: readability: name does not reflect variable purpose,
    // consider other naming, e.g. "bestPriceShop"
    // TODO review: unnecessary object instantiation. 
    // Obviously variables are declared too early / too far away from actual usage.
    Shop shopsNew = new Shop();
    Item itemsNew = new Item();
    Price priceNew = new Price();
    // TODO review: actually we need best price per item, 
    // that is, single variable "minPrice" will be not enough. 
    // Consider tracking min prices within a map indexed by item id.
    int minPrice = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < shops.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j ++){
            // TODO review: array price is empty (see declaration),
            // thus, this loop will complete without any iteration.
            // Obviously intention was something else, 
            // e.g. to iterate trough prices array of the shop[i]
            for (int p = 0; p < price.length; p++){
                if (price[p].price < minPrice){
                    itemsNew = items[j];
                    shopsNew = shops[i];
                    priceNew = price[p];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ItemWithBestPrice newPrice = new ItemWithBestPrice();
    newPrice.item = itemsNew;
    // TODO review: result of "equals" comparison is ignored. 
    // It seems like the code does not what it was intended to do.
    newPrice.shopName.equals(shopsNew);
    // TODO review: invalid syntax. did you ever tried to compile your code? :)
    newPrice.bestPrice = priceNew[];
    // TODO review: wrong variable type. it should be array of
    // ItemWithBestPrice according to function declaration.
    return newPrice;
}
```

Comment: ого спасибо))) развернутый ответ...

Comment: пока что не за что. :) рекомендую повторить раздел про работу с массивами и начать исправлять код с двух последних комментариев, так чтобы код компилировался, а затем уже разруливать вложенные циклы.